# Automation error when closing and saving workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro to extract data from an active Excel file, by pasting some formula I prepared on one workbook ("Processor*") into a target workbook ("INJ*"), then copying the resulting values to the "Processor*" workbook.

The macro works if I have the two required workbooks open (i.e. partial filename "Processor*", and partial filename "INJ*").

I'm hoping to request setting a folder, look through all Excel files in the set folder, extract data from each of the "INJ*" files in this folder, and save all results to "Processor*" file. Also, if it is possible for the macro to be case **insensitive**, recognizing the "TABLE" worksheet of "INJ*", whether named "TABLE" or "Table".

NB: WorkbookByName is a Function, Tim helped me with, for recognizing workbooks by partial name.

**My original code which works:**

```
  Dim wbProc As Workbook, wbInj As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet
  Dim sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet
 
  Set wbProc = WorkbookByName("Proc*")
  Set wbInj = WorkbookByName("INJ*")

  If wbProc Is Nothing Or wbInj Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "missing workbook(s)!"
  End If

  Set sh1 = wbProc.Sheets("Extractor")
  Set sh2 = wbProc.Sheets("calculation")
  Set sh3 = wbInj.Sheets("Manager Report")
  Set sh4 = wbInj.Sheets("TABLE")
  'Set sh4 = WorksheetByName("Table*")
                       
  sh1.Range("J13:Q19").Copy sh4.Range("J13")
      
    'The below will delete the $ sign, and activate the VLOOKUP Function in Cell J18 of my processing formula after they are copied to the INJ* file
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = sh4.Range("J18")
    myCell.Value = Right(myCell.Value, Len(myCell.Value) - 1) 'deletes first charater in the set cell (myCell, i.e. Cell J18)
    
    'Conditional format any value that requires attention so i can cross-check
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh4.Range("K18:Q18")
    '
    For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value2 = "Check" Then
    sh4.Range(cell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
    End If
    Next cell
        
                    
  Dim lrow As Long
  sh4.Range("J19:Q19").Copy
        'Select empty cell, paste value, and also paste (conditional) format if any
  lrow = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  sh2.Range("A" & lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  sh2.Range("A" & lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

**New code. I get an error, even though it succeeds in opening the first file:**

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile) 'MIGHT NOT NEED THIS
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    'Below is where I put my original working code, although a little modified
      DoEvents
      
              Dim wbProc As Workbook, wbInj As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet
              Dim sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet
         
              Set wbProc = WorkbookByName("Proc*")
              Set wbInj = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
              
              If wbProc Is Nothing Or wbInj Is Nothing Then
              MsgBox "missing workbook(s)!"
              End If
              
              Set sh1 = wbProc.Sheets("Extractor")
              Set sh2 = wbProc.Sheets("calculation")
              Set sh3 = wbInj.Sheets("Manager Report")
              Set sh4 = wbInj.Sheets("TABLE")
              
              sh1.Range("J13:Q19").Copy sh4.Range("J13")
              
            'The below will delete the $ sign, and activate the VLOOKUP Function in Cell J18 of my processing formula after they are copied to the INJ* file
            Dim myCell As Range
            Set myCell = sh4.Range("J18")
            myCell.Value = Right(myCell.Value, Len(myCell.Value) - 1) 'deletes first charater in the set cell (myCell, i.e. Cell J18)
            
            'Conditional format any value that requires attention so i can cross-check 
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = sh4.Range("K18:Q18")
            '
            For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value2 = "Check" Then
            sh4.Range(cell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
            Next cell
                
                            
          Dim lrow As Long
          sh4.Range("J19:Q19").Copy
                'Select empty cell, paste value, and also paste (conditional) format if any
          lrow = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
          sh2.Range("A" & lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
          sh2.Range("A" & lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        
      
    
    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)
      
    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Error message
[image: Here is an image of the error message I receive]

Comment: You say you keep getting an error. But you forgot to include the error in your post. Please add it so that we can understand what is wrong.

Comment: Hi CherryDT,

Thank you for calling my attention to this. I've added an image showing the received error. Thank you for the anticipated assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you open same file twice 
here

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile) 'MIGHT NOT NEED THIS
```

and here

```
Set wbInj = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
```

so when `close` use

```
wbInj.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Wow! A big huge "THANKS" to you Mo! You were absolutely right. That totally fixed it. I actually meant to deactivate the first 'set statement' you referred to, but I forgot. Thank you! Much gratitude sir!